# Make a bucket public in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I set a bucket in Amazon S3 so all the files are publicly read-only by default?

Comment: I'm annoyed this question was flagged as off topic. AWS is critical for serious programmers. I would add u can use cli sync command with acl argument like this: `aws s3 sync ./local-folder-name s3://remote-bucket-name --acl=public-read`

Comment: This answer to a similar post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23102551/475882

Answer (score 531, accepted):

You can set a bucket policy as detailed in this blog post:

http://ariejan.net/2010/12/24/public-readable-amazon-s3-bucket-policy/

---

As per @robbyt's suggestion, create a bucket policy with the following JSON:

```json
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Important**: replace `bucket` in the `Resource` line with the name of your bucket.

Comment: When using official AWS CLI `arn:aws:s3:::bucket` also needs to be added to the `Resource` array. (So without the `/*`.) I hope this helps others who were struggling with this like me.

Comment: My bad. This is needed only if you plan to `sync`, not just view the bucket.

Comment: To support anonymous access through python's boto, in addition to setting this policy, I also had to grant `List` privilege to `Everyone` in the Properties > Permissions section of the bucket.

Comment: what is the rule of writeing Version?
I am using current date 2017-11-16, it reports:Error: The policy must contain a valid version string

Comment: @Timothy.Li did you remember to wrap it in quotes? `"2017-11-16",`

Comment: I am getting Access denied when doing this.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html   Refer this Documentation will help you to fix this

Comment: @WalterMonecke you might need to make your bucket public acl
`aws s3api put-bucket-acl --acl public-read --bucket your-bucket`

Comment: although this works but for some reason it makes the resourece download when clicking on it (intead of opening it in the browser)

Comment: For other noobs, "Version" is a specific AWS thing --  [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291006/aws-policy-must-contain-valid-version-string). As of 2017, the options were `2012-10-17` and `2008-10-17`.

Answer (score 61):

Amazon provides a policy generator tool:

https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

After that, you can enter the policy requirements for the bucket on the AWS console:

https://console.aws.amazon.com/s3/home

Comment: this is official document of <<Using Bucket Policies and User Policies>>
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/using-iam-policies.html

Comment: Great link. Syntax is so complex they had to write a generator for it.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2