# how can I change the display of the image URL? (carrierwave, amazon s3, rails and heroku)

Tags: ruby, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using carrierwave to upload images. With the advice received from here, I opened up an Amazon S3 account to host my images for heroku. However, this is the image_url that is displayed on my website

https://appname.s3.amazonaws.com/images/image/84/74e0f4dfca.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=XXXXXXXXXXX2XXXXXXX&Signature=XxXXxXX2XXxXxXXXXXxxx&Expires=1363404606

How can I display a very shortened version of this? preferable just 
"/image/84/74e0f4dfca.jpg"

Comment: Is it OK if the images are publicly-accessible?  If so, you might be able to drop the AWSAccessKeyId and Signature

Comment: yes, the images need to be available to everyone and users should be able to upload images into it as well (using carrierwave)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's OK for the images to be public, perhaps you can make the [bucket publicly accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547046/make-a-bucket-public-in-amazon-s3).  It sounds like [there are some GUI tools](http://raventools.com/blog/how-to-make-files-publicly-accessible-on-amazon-s3/) that should make this easier.  If the bucket's public, it stands to reason that you could drop the authentication from the URL.  I haven't used S3, so someone with more experience should definitely chime in.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to make this part of the image URL: https://appname.s3.amazonaws.com/image/etc, be changed to https://appname.com/image/etc? I'm basically trying to not display s3.amazonaws.com whenever image_url is retrieved. If I use CNAME, I don't think that will help...

Comment: Yes, you can make your app act as an [HTTP proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_proxy).  Of course, beware of increasing the request times for your end-users.