# IOError: cannot identify image file -- works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, python-imaging-library

I know there are a zillion questions and answers about this error on StackOverflow, and I have read them all and tried many of their suggestions (Pillow instead of PIL, io.BytesIO instead of stringIO), but I'm still getting the same issue with the following:

I'm working on code to process images from S3 -- specifically to resave them as JPGs, rotate them if necessary, and create various thumbnails.  The relevant part of the code gets a list of URLs referring to images on S3.  I can confirm that, yes, the images are on S3 in the location specified by the URL.  On each URL I call the following:

```
def process_new_image(file_url):        
    # Load the image and make it a PIL object
    try:
        fd = urllib.urlopen(file_url)
        image_file = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
        image = Image.open(image_file)
    except Exception, e:
        # ===> This is where the issue happens. <====
        raise

    # Read the exif data and potentially rotate the image
    transpose = Transpose()
    transposed_image = transpose.process(image)

    # Resave the image as a jpeg
    new_image_data = io.BytesIO()
    transposed_image.save(new_image_data, 'jpeg', quality=100)
    new_image_data.seek(0)

    try:
        self.image.save('image', ContentFile(new_image_data.read()), save=True)
    except Exception, e:         
        raise

    new_image_data.seek(0)
    self.process_thumbnails(new_image_data)
```

This code works fine locally.  But when I run it on my staging environment in Heroku, I get "IOError: cannot identify image file."  It fails on JPGs, PNGs, and GIFs, which all work locally.

Specifics about my environment:

Django==1.5.1

Pillow==2.1.0

pilkit==1.1.1

Python 2.7.3 (on both)

Locally Pillow compiled with:

```
--- TKINTER support available
--- JPEG support available
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
*** TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support not available
--- FREETYPE2 support available
*** LITTLECMS support not available
*** WEBP support not available
```

On Heroku Pillow compiled with:

```
       *** TKINTER support not available
       --- JPEG support available
       --- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
       --- TIFF G3/G4 (experimental) support available
       --- FREETYPE2 support available
       --- LITTLECMS support available
       *** WEBP support not available
```

Comment: Hmmm, this appears to be related to the underlying S3 bucket.  If the image is public, then the code works.  If not, then not.  But I can't seem to get the image to be public by default.  I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547046/make-a-bucket-public-in-amazon-s3, but it did not work -- only manually setting the image to public works, which is obv. not an option...

Comment: Yes, can set the file programmatically as public with         k.set_acl('public-read').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue related to S3 bucket.  Image needed to be made public in bucket.  Question should be closed.