# Can't access image saved in bucket in Javascript code

Tags: javascript, django, amazon-s3

I have a django project that uploads files to a AWS S3 bucket. The uploaded files and the static files are shown correctly if they are rendered in the template using the `{% static %}` tag for example. However, when I want to access the image in a javascript code using `model_object.image.url`, the image doesn't show up. I inspected the code, took the url that was rendered in the js code and pasted it on the browser, it gives me this error:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters</Message>
<RequestId>xxxx</RequestId><HostId>xxx</HostId>
</Error>
```

**Some more information that might be useful:**

The user uploads an image, then he can crop the image. I use [Croppie](http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/) for this, it is a js library that uses the url of the image like this:

```
$('.div').croppie({
    url: '{{ model_object.image.url }}',
});
```

Everything works locally. It is a problem with AWS I clearly don't understand.

Following `solarissmoke` comment, I added this bucket policy to my bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1468082822770",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1468082812651",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::criptolibertad/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, it still doesn't work. I noticed the url rendered in the template that doesn't work looks like this:

> https://criptolibertad.s3.amazonaws.com/Django/0_squashmigrations.jpeg?Signature=HFDdOYvrfqz5DG...

If I open the resource directly from my bucket, the url looks like this:

> https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/criptolibertad/Django/0_squash+migrations.jpeg?X-Amz-Date=201607...

I also right clicked on the folder and selected `Make Public` just in case.

Any advice will help.

Comment: Looks like your S3 bucket/objects are not public, which they need to be to access them without authentication. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176926/how-to-make-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket-public-by-default) for some ideas.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks for the comment, I added a policy now. But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the links above point to different paths, one is the file `Django/0_squash+migrations.jpeg` the other is `Django/0_squashmigrations.jpeg`.
The latter is the one not working for me and it seems it's missing a + character (space?); I cannot access that file at all (I get an access error). I'm going to assume that's just a typo on your part.

Being familiar with [your code](https://github.com/asfaltboy/CrHisoka/) (let me know if you want the link redacted), I have simulated the image upload, and even copied your policy over to my bucket.

What I noticed is that my `model_objecct.image.url` differs from yours in that it includes the AWSAccessKeyId like so:

```
> fs = FeralSpirit.objects.all()[1]
> print(fs.imagen.url)
https://so38134984.s3.amazonaws.com/OrillaLibertaria/Users/pavel/dev/temp/so38134984/rainbow_dash2.png?Signature=****&Expires=*****&AWSAccessKeyId=*******
```

The link in your example only includes the signature, thus the error message you see is very appropriate.

In fact, we can access [the image above](https://criptolibertad.s3.amazonaws.com/Django/0_squash+migrations.jpeg) without any query strings just ok.

If you're trying to remove the query string parameters, since this will be a publicly accessible bucket, try adding [`AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False`](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/blob/master/storages/backends/s3boto.py#L214) to your Django settings. This should generate the url without any query string parameters:

```
> fs = FeralSpirit.objects.all()[1]
> fs.imagen.url
'https://so38134984.s3.amazonaws.com/OrillaLibertaria/Users/pavel/dev/temp/so38134984/rainbow_dash2.png'
```

Which is still publicly accessible of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer man, I just edited and actualized the question.

Comment: Your question now has little to do with S3, I suggest you edit back the question, and ask a new one

Comment: To start you off, inspect the chrome developer tools log for any errors

Comment: @tutuDajaju I added the error to the question... I ran out of ideas.

Comment: Googling "Image blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy" leads to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25577981/484127) and [AWS S3 documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) for info. I feel bad polluting the question with a CORS issue, therefor I have reverted this question to it's original form to help others with a similar problem. If you still have an issue with CORS, open a separate question ([use your latest revision source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/0ebc65d4-90b7-4c30-acf5-e298a0cde8c7/view-source)).

Comment: Ok @tutuDajuju I agree. However, given that I've tried everything that came to my mind, even asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365182/image-saved-con-amazon-s3-bucket-not-showing-on-html5-canvas-crossorigin-issue) new question with no answer till now, I decided to hack my way out of this in a weird way. Thanks for all your attention. GL HF.

Comment: Sure thing I've answered that question @alejoss . Please remember to mark answers as accepted if they helped you resolve the issue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to **tutuDajajo** and his answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365182/image-saved-con-amazon-s3-bucket-not-showing-on-html5-canvas-crossorigin-issue) question I asked when I narrowed down the issue, I found the problem and the solution:

Croppie.js was trying to load the image into an HTML5 canvas. Croppie.js automatically added `crossorigin="anonymous"` to the image. But the image was missing the correct CORS headers and the canvas was therefore "tainted".

I found out that changing Croppie.js source and removing `crossorigin="anonymous"` worked partially: The image was loaded correctly into the canvas, but it was impossible to export it and get the base64 image I needed to send to the server.

The real solution was to change my bucket CORS configuration, from this:

`<AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>`

to this:

`<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>`

BTW. AWS documentation is not clear about the `AllowedHeader` options.