# Image saved con Amazon S3 bucket not showing on HTML5 canvas. Crossorigin issue

Tags: html, canvas, amazon-s3, cors

I have an image saved on my AWS S3 bucket. This is my CORS configuration:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Also, the bucket has this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1468082822770",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1468082812651",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::criptolibertad/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the image: https://criptolibertad.s3.amazonaws.com/Django/0_startproject.jpeg , as you can see, it is public. I use a library called [Croppie](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie) that tries to load the image into a canvas. But the canvas doesn't show the image I don't know why. The js looks like this:

```
croppie_div.croppie('bind', {
    url: "{{ carta_magicpy.imagen_base.url }}",
    points:  [10,10,300,600]
});
```

That `url` attribute is just a variable rendered by Django. It looks like this when it is rendered:

```
<img style="opacity: 0;" src="https://criptolibertad.s3.amazonaws.com/Django/0_startproject.jpeg" crossorigin="anonymous" class="cr-image">
```

Notice the `crossorigin` attribute. I went into Croppie's source and removed that attribute. But then I get the error:

> Image from origin ... has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource

How can I solve this?

Comment: The change in behavior seems to suggest that CORS configuration on the bucket is correct and `crossorigin="anonymous"` was also correct.  That is both sensible and confusing since it implies it should have been working.  Have you done any testing with different browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the CORS headers are still not set correctly. This [related Croppie issue #119](https://github.com/Foliotek/Croppie/issues/119) mentions you can check that by looking at the response headers.

It's [pretty easy to inspect the headers with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12173990/how-can-you-debug-a-cors-request-with-curl), for the image stored in your bucket:

```
curl -I -H "Origin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365182" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" https://criptolibertad.s3.amazonaws.com/Django/0_startproject.jpeg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: 9AaMwS9s2Im+OV6YlzVKrDW8RnbQqFt4Ygc+pRa3XM4iDmnJqlO8DQ7EjvpT4W4GnhGc0IvoQeI=
x-amz-request-id: CD4E7C50B5186192
Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 07:54:52 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 09 Jul 2016 05:13:33 GMT
ETag: "5733f7cd0187eb3a840bbe83e2c66a9b"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 33402
Server: AmazonS3
```

As opposed to the properly set up CORS headers on e.g imgur:

```
curl -I -H "Origin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365182" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" http://i.imgur.com/HMf7XWD.jpg
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Last-Modified: Wed, 06 Jul 2016 15:07:13 GMT
ETag: "7b01be4b9235542038f6d9793cc2c620"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Fastly-Debug-Digest: f94b623450bb8143aff369600bf855d6332bb44c12070f02b0fc95648eac6ef3
cache-control: public, max-age=31536000
Content-Length: 2457350
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 07:55:15 GMT
Age: 277937
Connection: keep-alive
X-Served-By: cache-iad2131-IAD, cache-fra1232-FRA
X-Cache: HIT, HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 1, 1
X-Timer: S1468569315.725739,VS0,VE2
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Server: cat factory 1.0
```

As you can see the main difference is that imgur returns the headers `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, while your S3 bucket does not.

I have followed the [official Amazon documentation on the subject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/EditingBucketPermissions.html) and applied the [modified CORS configuration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) to my own bucket, the difference from your configuration is [the `AllowedHeader` element](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#cors-allowed-headers), which defines the headers to allowed in response. I set my bucket to:

```
<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

Here are the resulting headers on the image stored in my bucket:

```
curl -I -H "Origin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38365182" -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: GET" https://so38134984.s3.amazonaws.com/rainbow_dash.png
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: ANxPKoL3JDsLDGerTf8gdcyRU7U4Ozg4eMYJ9ADlX/2qcBmx0dsmAbZxv2h/tFfQIXbkAs+x5iA=
x-amz-request-id: 737E30AE2F8634FC
Date: Fri, 15 Jul 2016 07:53:55 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
Last-Modified: Mon, 04 Jul 2016 20:09:19 GMT
ETag: "3ad1bb64b913c2eadab216b96034b990"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 148647
Server: AmazonS3
```

I assume my image will now work properly in your Croppie script.

Comment: It worked! ... thanks man. BTW I do believe AWS docs have insufficent details about the `<AllowedHeader>` options.

Comment: Definitely! Amazon has a serious case of mismanaging the tech support

Comment: Reference docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html