# How do I use the aws cli to set permissions on files in an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to the aws cli and I've spent a fair amount of time in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#cli-aws-s3) but I can't figure out how to set permissions on files after I've uploaded them. So if I uploaded a file with:

`aws s3 cp assets/js/d3-4.3.0.js s3://example.example.com/assets/js/`

and didn't set access permissions, I need a way to set them. Is there an equivalent to `chmod 644` in the aws cli?

And for that matter is there a way to view access permission?

I know I could use the `--acl public-read` flag with `aws s3 cp` but if I didn't, can I set access without repeating the full copy command?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The awscli supports two groups of S3 actions: [s3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html) and [s3api](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/).

You can use [aws s3api put-object-acl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-acl.html) to set the ACL permissions on an existing object.

The [logic behind there being two sets of actions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/leveraging-the-s3-and-s3api-commands/) is as follows:

- `s3`: high-level abstractions with file system-like features such as `ls`, `cp`, `sync`
- `s3api`: one-to-one with the low-level S3 APIs such as `put-object`, `head-bucket`

In your case, the command to execute is:

```
aws s3api put-object-acl --bucket example.example.com --key assets/js/d3-4.3.0.js --acl public-read
```

Comment: Bonus: you can also use `get-object-acl`  to see the existing permissions. `aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket bucket.name --key path/to/file.ext`

Comment: Any way to do this for all files in a bucket? CLI doesn't seem to accept wild cards for the --key parameter.

Comment: @PrgTrdr You can apply a bucket policy (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176926/how-to-make-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket-public-by-default) or apply an ACL for each object, but that has to be done object-by-object. There are also third-party tools (such as http://s3browser.com/share-s3-bucket-edit-acls.php).

Comment: could this be hidden away any more than it is?

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden I am used to GCP and only getting into AWS now. I am surprised by how much more user-friendly GCP is in almost every way imaginable.

Comment: @Macindows you're not wrong - AWS for engineers and GCP for developers