# S3 image read/write from Beanstalk/EC2 Web application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application (Elastic Beanstalk managed PHP on a Linux EC2 instance) that allows the user to upload images.

My concern is that if I upload my code I would first have to download all the images then re-upload them with my new code if they stay on EC2.  So the obvious solution seems to be to move the image directory to S3.

The approaches I've found so far are a mounted drive or the SDK.  What I'm finding is that for both approachs it seems Elastic Beanstalk is running in a write protected drive location that is preventing me from accessing the other approaches.

For instance, for the mounted drive, I can't recurse up enough directories to access the mounted drive.  Beanstalk is running in /var/app/current/ and the mounted drive is located /var/s3-{bucket mount name}.  If I try to access it (../../s3-{bucket mount name}) it looks for it in the same folder as my app.

When I followed the instructions for the SDK I installed it in ec2-user.  So it's located /home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php and as before I can't access that folder either (even from a require statement)!

Where do I go from here?  I've searched and read everything I can find that seems helpful and I'm not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have worked and I like it a lot better than other solutions:

I am using a bucket permission policy allowing access only to a specific URL as found: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4

This allows me to restrict access to my images (at least as far as I've been able to attempt) except for those coming from my web host.  I will still be using the API for file writing and if for some reason I find I need to list a directory.

As for my portion about including the composer.json file, I started uploading that instead of trying to reference the autoload.php file from my code.  And used the **DIR** for the include paths.  Both of those were critical pieces I would not have thought of without Christian's help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure I understand what you mean by it looking in the same folder as your app, but here is my approach to file read/write to S3 from a PHP based web application:

1) Create a new bucket for your application. This bucket can be separate from the bucket that manages your Elastic Beanstalk project.

2) In your bucket, go to permissions->bucket policy and add this policy to make your images public. **Important:** Replace BUCKET_NAME with the actual name of your bucket

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1397632521960",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1397633323327",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176926/how-to-make-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket-public-by-default)

3) Create a composer.json file with Amazon SDK and replace with whatever version you want. Place composer.json in the root of your project folder. (When you upload your project code, Elastic Beanstalk does its magic for you and will install all composer packages).

```
{
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.27.1",
    }
}
```

4) Include this at the top of the PHP file that handles file upload.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
```

5) Create an S3Client object using the AWS PHP SDK. Replace YOUR_KEY, YOUR_SECRET, and YOUR_BUCKET_REGION with the correct values. Again, add this to the same file.

```
$client = S3Client::factory(
     [
         'credentials' =>
          [
                 'key'    => 'YOUR_KEY',
                 'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET'
             ],
          'region' => 'YOUR_BUCKET_REGION',
          'version' => 'latest'
         ]
);
```

6) Now finally, after all that fun setup, here is how you can put an image object into S3 when a user uploads a file. Replace BUCKET_NAME with the exact name of your bucket, FILE_NAME.JPG with the destination file name on S3, and PATH/TO/TEMP_FILE.JPG with the temporary path where the image is being stored on your Elastic Beanstalk server.

```
$client->putObject([
                    'Bucket' => 'BUCKET_NAME',
                    'Key' => 'FILE_NAME.JPG',
                    'Body' => fopen('PATH/TO/TEMP_FILE.JPG', 'rb'),
                    'ACL' => 'public-read'
                   ]);
```

7) Okay, so that handles file writing. Now once you want to show the user the uploaded file, you can do so with a regular  tag. Again, replacing all capitalized fields with their correct values:

```
<img src="https://s3-YOUR_BUCKET_REGION.amazonaws.com/BUCKET_NAME/FILE_NAME.JPG" alt="My S3 image">
```

8) You now should have a web application with image write/read capabilities to Amazon S3.

Comment: Thank you!  I'm not 100% sure it answers everything but it helps a lot!  Some of the things I think I was missing ghat you helped to click were:   1.  I don't have to reference the composer location, I configure it with the Json file within my code. 2.  How to handle the permissions on the s3 side.  I had just figured out the URL access last night and seen the permissions needed (I thought giving ec2 access would be enough to serve it) but then I didn't know how to apply it to all!   Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! If there is anything else that isn't clear, just mention it and I'll try to add to my answer.

Comment: Is it better to put the KEY/SECRET in the actual PHP factory file?  Or should I set them as environment variables in Beanstalk and reference them dynamically?  I'm not sure if it makes a difference or if one is safer than the other.  I also would REALLY like to keep the image private outside of the web server.

Comment: Both should be equally safe as far as I know.                                                        
                                                                                                                           As for your second question, I suggest you visit the link I have attached. You can't have images on your website be truly private, but you can make authentication part of the url. This way they are considered private enough that random people can't find them: https://www.quora.com/Are-Facebook-pictures-really-private-or-are-they-hosted-on-Facebook-servers

Comment: Does the AWS part of "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }   Mean that it's only authenticated AWS users?  I understand some of what the article was talking about but not really how I would implement it.