# Getting 403 error inspite of adding AWS static file-path to CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST django-cors-headers

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, django-cors-headers

I am using django-summernote to my text-field. This should make my text-field look somewhat like the image below

[image]

Now the static files for the above above are stored in my AWS S3 bucket. I am getting a `403 error` in the browsers console and below is how my text field looks like right now

[image]

The 403 error in the console looks like below
[image]

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://some_bucket_66d.s3.amazonaws.com/static/summernote/font/summernote.woff?1d9aeaaff0a8939558a45be6cd52cd4c. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).[Learn More]
>   downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "summernote" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1): bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: https://some_bucket_6d.s3.amazonaws.com/static/summernote/font/summernote.woff?1d9aeaaff0a8939558a45be6cd52cd4c

So to solve this error I did 
`pip install django-cors-headers`

Added

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

Added it to my middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
...
]
```

And added the below 3 links to my whitlist in my django settings. I don't know what `http://127.0.0.1:9000` is for but I just let it be there anyways as it was in the https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/ page

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "https://some_bucket_66d.s3.amazonaws.com", #This is the bucket path as you see in the error above
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000"
]
```

I am still getting the same error even after whitelisting it in Django Cors what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it

> Tried the solution suggested by @jusrDare. NOw the error message has changed to the below

`downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "summernote" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:1): status=2147746065 source: https://some_bucket_66d.s3.amazonaws.com/static/summernote/font/summernote.woff?1d9aeaaff0a8939558a45be6cd52cd4c`

Also if you don't want to do AllowedOrigin as `*` you can try the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://www.your-site.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://www.your-site.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Any way both of them are giving me the same error

Comment: Adding CORS allows other sites to access your content; it doesn't allow you to access other sites' content. So none of that will have any affect. I don't know anything about this package, but you likely have an installation or configuration error somewhere. If you think there is a bug in the package, you can [file an issue](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/issues) on the Github page.

Answer (score 2):

Same error, will be back if I can figure it out today...

Back!

Tweaking the CORS header in AWS seemed to do the trick.

Replace the default CORS CONFIGURATION in your bucket permissions with:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

All I added from the default settings was the Conten-* Allowed header tag.

Not sure why this works EXACTLY, hopefully someone else can chime in.

Comment: It changed the error message. I no longer get the CORS erorr but a different one **See above**. Also  is `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` safe in production

Comment: I have upvoted your answer. However this has only done half the work. I resolved the CORS error only to give me a new error. Do you have any clue how we can resolve this second error

Answer (score 1):

You know, what's really weird is that I had the exact same problem (error 403: Forbidden) when trying to load .woff and .tff files (icon files), and it was solved by individually making all of the files public on my AWS S3 bucket (NOT the whole folder at once. Make them public individually. It worked for me).

Comment: You can make some or all objects in a bucket public by default with a bucket policy, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176926/how-to-make-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket-public-by-default)

Answer (score 1):

CORS configuration in AWS:

In the S3 console, the CORS configuration must be JSON.

You can check some examples on [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManageCorsUsing.html#cors-example-1) for JSON format:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Content-*",
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358173/correct-s3-cloudfront-cors-configuration). My problem was in CloudFront. Enable whitelist and method options fix.

Answer (score -1):

After spending an entire day of trying to make this work. I finally found a CDN with the summernote fonts after that I did not have to worry about CORS

In my django templates just added the code below

```
    <style>
      @font-face {
            font-family: "summernote";
            font-style: normal;
            font-weight: normal;
            src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/font/summernote.eot");
            src: url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/font/summernote.eot") format("embedded-opentype"),
            url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/font/summernote.woff") format("woff"),
            url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/font/summernote.ttf") format("truetype");
        }
    </style>
```

You can get the CDN from this link https://cdnjs.com/libraries/summernote