# How to provide public access to an aws s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon s3 I have created a bucket and set cloudwatch.Logs are being generated for audit and trace. But with s3, able to share individual file download links only. Any option to set complete bucket /folder to public and users can access that? I tried updating bucket policy but no use.

[Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176926/how-to-make-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket-public-by-default/23102551#23102551) I tried.

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1397632521960",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1397633323327",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketnm/*",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But still below issue.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>C3A5489DCEA8A2EA</RequestId>
<HostId>qjKSgWX6fnyPlAiCgq0RxxqK2ZEHZqEewahAlsdIAgznNRmezwif6NoP67FD9ysuH1psi4lO4m8=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: create a bucket IAM policy

Comment: I tried the policy in this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176926/how-to-make-all-objects-in-aws-s3-bucket-public-by-default/23102551#23102551 First answer. But still same error.

Comment: ok, when you open the Policy tab on the s3 bucket, what is in the "Block public access" section?

Comment: it is unchecked

Comment: Reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteAccessPermissionsReqd.html I think your setup is what you need, only this: "You can use a bucket policy to grant public read permission to your objects. However, the bucket policy applies only to objects that are owned by the bucket owner. If your bucket contains objects that aren't owned by the bucket owner, the bucket owner should use the object access control list (ACL) to grant public READ permission on those objects." - owner = account id, it would be your case only if you uploaded from a different AWS account.

Comment: "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name>/*"  are you using your bucket name?

Comment: yes, I am using my bucket name only

Comment: petrch has mentioned a common issue in cross-account scenarios, did you verify the owner of the objects you want to publish?

Comment: yeah it is a new bucket created from my account only.

Comment: @udaykiran How is the object being accessed? Is it via a browser URL (where are you getting the URL), or an API call? Firstly, I would recommend against making log information public since it can reveal details about your infrastructure. Secondly, you have granted access to any AWS entity (`"Principal":{"AWS":["*"]}`), which is not quite "public". To be public, you would use `"Principal":"*"`.

Comment: Hi John, still same