# AWS S3: Access denied if file is within folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am uploading several files and folders to an S3 bucket. What I'm, uloading looks like this:

```
File1
File2
File3
img/
    File4
    File5
```

meaning files 4 & 5 are in folder img.

I want all of these files to be publicly accessible, so I specifiy the following permissions when uploading:

[image]

Upload succeeds, but for whatever reason, I cannot access the files in img from the browser. Everything outside img is fine (i.e. Files1-3), but when trying to access File4 or File5, I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried selecting the folder and choosing Actions => Make public using ACL

[image]

But I still get Access Denied when accessing files in this folder.

I've also tried applying the ACL to the actual objects under img/, not the img/ folder itself, but I still get the same result.

Comment: Apply the ACL to the actual objects under `img/`, not the `img/` folder itself.

Comment: By the way, if you simply want to make all objects in the bucket publicly readable then it's typically better to [use an S3 bucket policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19176926).

Comment: @jarmod I tried that with no success. Added this to the question

Comment: Double-check the ACL on the object in question using [aws s3api get-object-acl](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object-acl.html) and then re-test a browser fetch of the image from a new browser or incognito session or using curl/wget.

Answer (score 1):

Using ACLs is discouraged these days -- they are a hold-over from the earlier days of S3. In fact, these days it is encouraged to [Disable ACLs for all new buckets - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ensure-object-ownership.html).

Instead, **attach a Bucket Policy** to the bucket. This policy will grant permission for *anyone* to download any object from the bucket, but they need to know the Key (filename) of the object since it doesn't grant permission to list the contents of the bucket:

```json
{
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
     {
       "Effect": "Allow",
       "Principal": "*",
       "Action": "s3:GetObject",
       "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::MY-BUCKET/*"
     }
   ]
}
```