# Accessing S3 Public URL for iframe

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I'm storing files in Amazon S3 and want to view them in HTML in an iframe src but I'm having trouble constructing the URL required to access files from S3. I'm using Python's Boto library, and my permission settings allow for public access. This is what I tried...

```
https://[BUCKET_NAME].s3.amazonaws.com/[UNIQUE_KEY]?AWSAccessKeyId=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

However, this is throwing an error.

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0A115D93B8454F2F</RequestId>
<HostId>
YxcOdP2zYWw8Vl1p137Ipaqrcx3sPN68PEFRb8H9Kv5XlyRtye7xB0ZuVB/mvDWp
</HostId>
</Error>
```

**UPDATE:** There were some issues with the public settings, which are now fixed but when I enter the above in the iframe src, my browser starts downloading the file. I want to simply view it!

Comment: Perhaps you could put the content in a bucket that's publicly readable, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547046/make-a-bucket-public-in-amazon-s3

Comment: @AlexWoolford Hi Alex, bucket is public. Thx

Comment: If you're getting that error message then clearly it isn't. So you need to check the bucket permissions settings to see how it's configured. Is the AWS access key correct?

Comment: @SimeonVisser I've resolved the public settings issue, see update and thx.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign content_type correctly when uploading file to S3. If browser recognizes the file content-type, it shows the file instead of store the file. See how to assign content-type here: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key