# Image is not coming in html

Tags: html

Here is my main page code. It is working in the localhost but not on my website.
My website link where pics are not comming - bh007.hol.es. I have even added some images (1.PNG, 2.jpg, 3.PNG) in the ftp but then also its not working
heres the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="BlackHackers Co. Ltd. established in 2015 has launched digital India most ambitious project freedom 420, within the price range of 420 rupees">
<meta name="keywords" content="Cheapest smartphone in India, Affordable smartphone, Freedom 420, 4G smartphone under 500, Best smartphone 2016, Smartphone in 420">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Freedom 420 The best mobile to be get fooled</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmfiles/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmfiles/css/style.css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<style>
.nav > li > a { padding: 5px 13px; font-size:12px; color:#666; border-bottom:solid 2px #FFF}
.nav > li > a:hover{ background-color:#FFF; color:#0C8F0D; border-bottom:solid 2px #0C8F0D}
.pad_0{ padding:0}
.mob_no{color:#FF863B; font-size:12px; margin-top:23px; text-align:right}
.contact-btn{ background-color:#FF863B; color:#FFFFFF!important; border-radius:15px; font-weight:bold; padding: 5px 10px!important; border:solid 1px #FF863B!important}
.contact-btn:hover{ background-color:#FFFFFF!important; color:#FF863B!important; border:solid 1px #FF863B}
.header_img{ background-image:url(2.jpg); background-size:100% 100%; height:570px; border-bottom:solid 1px #005BA8}
.btn-buy{background-color:#1ABA1C; color:#FFFFFF;margin-top: 27%;margin-left: 34%; font-size: 20px;border-radius: 20px;font-weight: bold;padding: 8px 20px;}
.btn-buy:hover{ color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#1B971A}
.form-control{ border-radius:0px}
label{ font-weight:normal!important; color:#666666}
.selected-menu > a{ background-color:#FFF; color:#0C8F0D!important; border-bottom:solid 2px #0C8F0D!important}
.selected1-menu > a{ background-color:#FFFFFF!important; color:#FF863B!important; border:solid 1px #FF863B}
.selected-menu1{background-color:#FFF; color:#0C8F0D!important;}
.hlwitslogo{ margin-top:105px; float:left}
@media (max-width:991px) {
.hlwitslogo{ margin:15px auto!important;}
.hlwitslogo > span { margin-right:15px}
}
@media (min-width:769px) and (max-width:1024px){
    .header_img{ height:400px}
 .mob_no{ font-size:11px; text-align:center}
 .nav > li > a { padding: 5px 6px;}
 .navigation{ padding-left:0; padding-right:0}
 .halwits_logo{ width:27%; margin-left:15px;}
 .hlwitslogo{ margin-top:97px}
 .footer_img{ margin-top:18%}
 
} 
</style>
<script src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmfiles/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmfiles/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmfiles/js/general.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input[name="quantity"]').keyup(function() {
  var quantity = $(this).val();
  var price = ;
  var shipping = ;
  var final_price = quantity * price;
  $('.f_price').html(final_price);
  var final_shipping = quantity * shipping;
  $('.s_price').html(final_shipping);
  $('.t_price').html(final_price + final_shipping);
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="overflow-x: hidden;" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row visible-lg visible-md" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #005BA8">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:10px 0px">
                <div class="col-md-3"><a href="http://bh007.hol.es"><img src="1.png" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pad_0">
                    <p class="mob_no">CUSTOMER CARE NO. 0120-4001000, 4200470, 6619580</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 navigation" style="padding-top:15px">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                        <li class=""><a href="about.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="mission.html">MISSION AND VISION</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="contact.html" class="contact-btn">CONTACT US</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!------mobile menu start----->
    <div class="row header hidden-md hidden-lg" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="navbar-header" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; float:none"> <span style=" float:left; margin-left:10px;"><a href="http://bh007.hol.es"><img src="1.png" class="img-responsive" /></a> </span>
                        <div class="mini-submenu" style="display:block; float:right;padding:8px; border-radius:4px; margin:10px;"> <span class="icon-bar" style=" background-color:#FF5C19"></span> <span class="icon-bar" style=" background-color:#FF5C19"></span> <span class="icon-bar" style=" background-color:#FF5C19"></span> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group mobile_link hidden-md hidden-lg" style=" position:absolute; width:54%;z-index: 1000; left:-1000px">
      <a href="http://freedom251.com/home\" class="abtus "> <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Home </a>
      <a href="about.html" class="abtus "> <i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;ABOUT US </a>
      <a href="mission.html" class="abtus "> <i class="fa fa-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;MISSION AND VISION </a>
      <!--<a href="http://freedom251.com//cart" class="abtus "> <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;BUY NOW</a>-->
                        <!--<a href="#" class="abtus "> <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;MEDIA </a>-->
                        <a href="contact.html" class="abtus "> <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;CONTACT US </a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!------mobile menu end----->
    <div class="row header_img visible-lg visible-md">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <!--<a href="http://freedom251.com/cart"><button class="btn btn-buy">BUY NOW</button></a>-->
   <!--<button class="btn btn-buy" style="font-size:14px">Booking starts from 18th Feb - 6 AM onwards</button>-->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row visible-xs visible-sm">
 <img src="2.jpeg" class="img-responsive" />
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12 visible-md  visible-lg"> <img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_part.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin:15px auto" /> </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs visible-sm table-responsive" style="padding:0; margin-top:10px">
   <table class="table">
    <tr>
     <td><img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_part.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin:15px auto" /></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row first_con">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6"> <img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_freedom251.jpg" alt="freedom251" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <p>Freedom to Flaunt your Bread</p>
     <p>All your favourite Breads, Lolcats and jokes are rendered vivid and larger than life on the 4 inch (Only if your life is less than 4 inches) (10.2 cms) special "420" qHD IPS display.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row sec_con">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <p>Freedom to Capture</p>
     <p class="cam">Freedom 420 comes With a special "420" 3.2MP AF Rear Camera & .3MP Front camera capture best moments of your life with a special 'Low Quality Blur' Effect. Guranteed you will not get this feature in the I-Phone. Freedom 420 with its inbuilt touchless technology is Ideal for blurry Selfie. For Selfie lovers life just got a little more difficult. Still better than a pin hole camera.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 cam-spec"> <img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_freedom.jpg" alt="freedom" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row third_con">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-6"> <img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_freedom1.jpg" alt="freedom251" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <p>Freedom to throw your phone at somebody</p>
     <p>Don't let a moment to throw your phone to anyone that passes you by. Enjoy the boundless freedom of throwing your phone so that even if it breaks, you will never regret! throw this phone on your family, friends  
      or followers wherever you are with an enhanced hardness that gives you the ultimate bread you need at lightning fast speeds.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row fourth_con" style="background-image:url(https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_bgr.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position: 100% 10%;">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:5%; padding-bottom:5%">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <p style="margin-top:20%">Freedom to your fitness</p>
     <p style="font-size:20px; color:#48A645">Throw this phone at anybody and run away! Will enhance your stamina and will act as your personal trainer!! Never miss a chance to loose your weight by throwing this phone at anyone! It comes with a special feature called
                                            the "420 Bhaggo" feature for better hardness to break someone's head.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6"> <img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_freedom2.jpg" alt="freedom" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row six_con" style="border-top:solid 4px #0C8F0D;">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:5%; padding-bottom:5%">
    <div class="col-md-6"> <img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_freedom3.jpg" alt="freedom251" class="img-responsive" /> </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <p>Freedom to charge!</p>
     <p>You can even charge your Freedom 420! The greatest feature in this phone!</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row fifth_con">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="col-md-12 visible-md  visible-lg" style="padding-top:5%; padding-bottom:5%"> <img src="3.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin:15px auto"  /> </div>
   <div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs visible-sm table-responsive" style="padding:0; margin-top:10px">
    <table class="table">
     <tr>
      <td><img src="3.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="margin:15px auto; width:600px" /></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>    <div class="row">
  <div class="row" style="background-color:#FFF; padding-bottom:10px">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style="padding-right:0px;">
                    <div class="col-md-5 social col-xs-12">
                      
                            </div>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12"> <img src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fdmimages/img_footer.jpg" alt="freedom251" class="img-responsive footer_img"> </div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12  halwits_logo" style="padding-right:0px;" align="right"><span class="description hlwitslogo"><span style="float:left; margin-top:8px">Developed &amp; Managed By </span></span><a href="http://www.bh007.hol.es/" target="_blank"><img src="lol.jpg" alt="Halwits" class="img-responsive hlwitslogo" style="margin-left:10px"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 footer_txt">
                    <!--<p>&copy; Freedom 251 &nbsp;|&nbsp; All Rights Reserved &nbsp;|&nbsp; Privacy Policy<span>Design &amp; Developed by <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">Halwits</a></p>-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!---popup start--->
<div class="popup-bg" id="popup-bg-book" onClick="hideContactpopup()"></div>
<div class="popup-body" id="popup-book"> </div>
<!---popup end----->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-73802173-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the images seem to be not public accessible on S3. When opening the URI i'll get a ``AccessDenied``Error

Comment: then how do i display then?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547046/make-a-bucket-public-in-amazon-s3

Comment: u can see the images bh007.hol.es/1.PNG bh007.hol.es/2.jpg

Comment: yes this one is accessible

Comment: i want these images only

Comment: why are they not comming @Bernhard

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your code you have `img` src attribute is pointing to a relative link:

```
<img src="2.jpeg" class="img-responsive" />
```

if the file is not on the server in the same manner as you local then it will not render. So to ensure that it will work properly provide all the files in their respective location. Also make sure this class "img-responsive" is set correctly.

And if all else fails and the files are in the right location, make them absolute links instead.