# Upload Full Imagemagick to AWS Lambda and use with graphics magic module

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, imagemagick, gm

Here is a [prior post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046586/aws-lambda-not-working-along-with-the-gm-module/37660077/) that discusses how the pre-loaded Imagemagick is limited for security reasons on AWS Lambda.

> "Note: This update contains an updated /etc/ImageMagick/policy.xml
>   file that disables the EPHEMERAL, HTTPS, HTTP, URL, FTP, MVG, MSL,
>   TEXT, and LABEL coders"

I need to use the 'label' function (which works successfully on my development machine - example pic further below))

Within the discussion in the linked post, frenchie4111 generously offers use of a node module he created that uploads imagemagick to a lambda app:  github link https://github.com/DoubleDor/imagemagick-prebuilt

I would like to understand how uploading a fresh version of Imagemagick works, and how I will then use that version with the GM module that incorporates IM and nodejs together.

If I read correctly the full version of imagemagick will be reloaded to the address below each time my lambda app boots up ?

```
 /tmp/imagemagick
```

DoubleDor's readme directions provides the option below:

```
var imagemagick_prebuilt = require( 'imagemagick-prebuilt' );

var child_process = require( 'child_process' );

exports.handler = function( event, context ) {
    return q
        .async( function *() {
            imagemagick_bin_location = yield imagemagick_prebuilt();
            console.log( `ImageMagick installed:   ${imagemagick_bin_location}` );

            // ImageMagick logo creation test:
            // convert logo: logo.gif
            var convert_process = child_process
                .spawn( imagemagick_bin_location, [ 'logo:', 'logo.gif' ] )

            convert_process
                .on( 'close', function() {
                    context.success();
                } );
        } )();
};
```

What would I include/require to define 'gm' to work within my partial file below (in my nodejs lambda app)?

Will I need to edit the GM module too?

```
//imagemaker.js > gets included and called from another file that uploads picture to s3, and/or tweets it after picture is created in /tmp/filename.jpg   This works presently.. I can make and upload imagemagick text generated images but I just can't use the 'label' tool which scales text within appended gm images 

'use strict';

var Promise = require('bluebird');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var async = require('async');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

performers = [ { name: 'Matt Daemon', score: 99}, { name: “Jenifer Lawrence”, score: 101}
//created in a makeTitle function I omit for brevity sake.
url = “/temp/pathtotitlepicture.jpg” 

// function below successfully appends a gm title image created with other functions that I haven't included
 function makeBody(url){
    var img = gm(400,40)
        .append(url)
        .gravity('West')
        .fill('black')
        .quality('100')
        .font('bigcaslon.ttf')
        .background('#f0f8ff')
    for (var i = 0; i < performers.length; i++) {
      var pname = " " + (i+1) + ") " +performers[i].name;
      img.out('label:'+pname);
    };  
    img.borderColor('#c5e4ff')
         .border('5', '5')
         .write(url, function (err) {
           if (err) throw err;
             var stream = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/fooberry.jpg")
             return resolve(stream)
          });
  }
```

Just for fun, the image below shows what I've been able to do with gm(graphics magic) and imagemagick on my development machine that I'd now like to get working on AWS Lambda >> I really need that 'label' function and I guess that means learning how to get that whole library uploaded to AWS Lambda each time it boots!(?)

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @NudeCanalTroll  no, I'm sorry.  I'd like to understand it but went on to other things.  I still would like to implement it in a server-less way.

Comment: I posted a valid answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729088/how-can-i-install-graphicsmagick-or-imagemagick-on-aws-lambda/45555876#45555876