# How to setup GraphicsMagick for aws lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, graphicsmagick

I want to use GraphicsMagick for aws lambda function but I am unable to add GraphicsMagick env. into lambda.

Comment: You can upload node_modules folder with gm library and use it on lambda

Comment: but gm module require GraphicsMagick dependency.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729088/how-can-i-install-graphicsmagick-or-imagemagick-on-aws-lambda

Comment: I don't think this is a proper use case for lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

For executing the Graphicsmagick and Imagemagick into lambda you need to add the static Binaries.
use the below reference link for adding these binaries into lambda:
https://gist.github.com/basimhennawi/21c39f9758b0b1cb5e0bd5ee08b5be58