# AWS Lambda GraphicsMagick error: gm/convert binaries can't be found"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, graphicsmagick

I'm suing GraphicsMagick in a Lambda function with Node and I'm getting this error:

```
Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "convert" "/tmp/yH3Js6ALXVGGAokvIsij.png" "/tmp/a086ffd7-a143-4f83-8f6a-fcdd29b12630.png" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/gm/lib/command.js:232:12)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:213:12)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

So it says `the gm/convert binaries can't be found` which means the app isn't installed although the line `"gm": "^1.23.1"` is in package.json. Can you tell me now I can include the `gm/convert binaires` in the repo to make it work? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gm` is a NodeJS package for using `ImageMagick`. You still need `ImageMagick` itself.

You would need to install and compile `ImageMagick` for the Lambda environment. You can then upload it as a Lambda layer where your Lambda Function can sit on top of.

If you use `serverless`, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555876/1252647) that provides you the steps on how to build `ImageMagick` as a Lambda layer.

Comment: Jeez a lot of commands! He's talking about executing this code in the server, right? Does he mean he wants to include all this code in a bash file and let Lambda execute it upon deployment for example? (I can't comment on his answer).

Comment: No. You execute in a Linux machine to create the Lambda layer. If you're in Mac OSX or Windows, you have to use `docker` or `vagrant` to have to create a Lambda-compatible layer. Then, deploy that Lambda layer. Then, configure your Lambda Function to run on top of that Lambda Layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I got AmazonLinux running in a Docker container but I am still having difficulty understand how to do the rest done (get ImageMagick with all delegates, extract binaries from container, use them as a layer in AWS Lambda...). Is there any reference you can share apart of the bit and pieces we find in Google search?

Answer (score 0):

There is a static build of ImageMagick that you can deploy directly from this page.
https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications~image-magick-lambda-layer

Deploying will create a Lambda layer that you can then use in your Lambda function.

Note that you will still need the GraphicsMagick node.js library, which you can build on an Amazon Linux 2 AMI instance by running the following commands:

```
sudo yum update
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x  | sudo bash -
sudo yum install nodejs
mkdir nodejs
cd nodejs
npm init
npm install gm
cd ..
zip -r nodejslayer.zip ./nodejs
```

That zip file can then be directly uploaded to create a second Lambda layer. Both the ImageMagick and GraphicsMagick Lambda layers are necessary to successfully run your Lambda function.