# How to setup gm (GraphicsMagick) on aws lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I've been trying to get node gm to work on aws lambda.

I installed the imagemagick and graphicmagick libraries on an EC2 instance created from a lambda execution environment. I pointed the appPath to these libraries from gm.

I still get the following error -

`Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: /var/task/graphicsmagick/bin/identify "-ping" "-format" "%wx%h" "./resultant-file.jpg" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found`

Can anyone suggest me the right folder structure for such an app or any pointers as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should search this forum first. This question appears to be asked quite a bit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729088/how-can-i-install-graphicsmagick-or-imagemagick-on-aws-lambda. Does that help?

Comment: @fmw42 Did try it out as well, didn't really help. Followed the steps as per what was provided in the gist, I'm mainly confused about the folder structure.

Comment: Sorry, wish I could help more, but I do not know AWS Lambda. I had just hoped that the link would provide you a solution.

Comment: Which Node and GM versions are you using? Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58881623/1988983