# How to get access to AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to run a script from OpenTraffic repository, and it needs access to some AWS S3 buckets. I am unable to figure out how to get access to a particular AWS S3 bucket?

FYI:

- OpenTraffic is a open source platform to obtain and analyse dynamic traffic data : https://github.com/opentraffic
- The script I am trying to run: 
  https://github.com/opentraffic/reporter/blob/dev/load-historical-data/load_data.sh
- Documentation(https://github.com/opentraffic/reporter/tree/dev/load-historical-data) says: In order to run above script,
  access required to both s3://grab_historical_data, s3://reporter-drop-
  {prod, dev}.

Comment: Did you already come across this topic [Make a bucket public in Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547046/make-a-bucket-public-in-amazon-s3)? You need to make the bucket publicly available, with the right policy

Comment: yes.. but the bucket was created by contributors to Opentraffic... And ideally they should have made the buckets public.. However that is not the case... And getting access to the buckets is a requirement to run the code.. So I am not sure on how to proceed!

Comment: @RaviKiran I read the document in question and it is unclear what they mean by "access" -- it could mean *permission to access*, but it also could mean *the necessary Internet connectivity in order to access* (proper routing and firewall rules, or VPC endpoint, etc.)  It isn't clear what they intended.  You can't do anything about permissions without the help of the bucket or object owners.  What error do you experience?

Comment: @RaviKiran did you find solution to this problem ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response...@ Michael - sqlbot, the error basically says access denied. So As you said, the bucket owner has to grant permission.
@ muazfaiz No. I was not able to access the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Your're accessing the S3 buckets from r3.4xlarge ec2 instance according to the documentation link your share.

Firstly, You've to create a IAM role for ec2 instance and S3 access policy with it.

Create the ec2 instance and attach the IAM role to it because this is the only time you can to assign a role to it and launch it.

Role gives your ec2 instance access permission for s3 bucket.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response... I did this, however I am getting- acess denied. I guess as @Michael - sqlbot said, the bucket owner has to grant permission.