# AWS S3 bucket images not appearing in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

After finding that some large images were not appearing in my Rails app in Heroku, I opened an AWS account in the hope that they would be shown this way.

I uploaded my images to my S3 bucket and I registered the keys on Heroku, as per the tutorial on the Heroku site. Everything seems to be in place, so I referred to the images using the AWS link:

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="https://s3-ap-southeast- 
 1.amazonaws.com/globalenglish1/EnglishUp-113.jpg">
```

But this this didn't work so I guess something is missing. The only thing that I can think it might be is that I didn't start my app in Heroku with a Procfile, and I can't find any way of creating a procfile now that I already have my app deployed to Heroku. But I don't really know if this is necessary, it's just my guess.

If anyone can give me any pointers, I would be most grateful.

Comment: What do you mean by didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the description provided and visiting the image source it seems that the public access has not been provided to view this image.

Please check for AWS console that the images stored on S3 bucket are publicly accessible or not.

If not then please provide public access and then check again.

For making the bucket public please find the below mentioned link.

[Make a bucket public in Amazon S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547046/make-a-bucket-public-in-amazon-s3)

Comment: Thanks - silly me I didn't notice that you needed to make it public :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you have put with space `' '` on source URL like after `https://s3-ap-southeast-` it's with space see [**`URL`**](https://s3-ap-southeast-%20%20%201.amazonaws.com/globalenglish1/EnglishUp-113.jpg) from your post it's not showing Image while I put into browser, but after removing this space like [**`This URL`**](https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/globalenglish1/EnglishUp-113.jpg) it's showing image.

Check it out.