# How to set public read only access on Amazon S3 Bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have found a couple of similar questions on StackOverflow like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547046/make-a-bucket-public-in-amazon-s3) but they are quite old and it seems things have changed with S3 since then. They added these four settings which are quite confusing:
[image]
**If I turn these off, does it mean it makes my bucket writable by public?** 
In addition I also added this policy:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED/*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:user/REDACTED"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED",
            "arn:aws:s3:::REDACTED/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

and this CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>REDACTED</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I am trying to give public read access and restrict full access to a user I created in IAM.
**I would appreciate if someone could confirm that my settings are correct or in case they are not point me to the resources I need to get it right.**

Comment: Your policy seems wrong. From [the post](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2), set the policy and turn off the block public access (already done).

Comment: No, disabling Block Public Access does *not* make your bucket publicly writable (or readable). Disabling it simply allows you to make objects public.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find the right settings with your help!

Comment: yes I am having a similar issue.. the settings are unnecessarily confusing

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To make objects publicly **accessible**, use a policy like this:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicRead",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::examplebucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that use of `"Principal": "*"`, which is different to your policy that uses `"Principal": {"AWS": "*"}`.

This allows objects to be accessed (`GetObject`), but the content of the bucket cannot be listed. That would require `ListBucket` permissions on the bucket itself (without the `/*`).

You will also need to **turn off the two Block Public Access settings** related to Bucket Policies.

Comment: +1 for explaining the permissions for listing bucket contents and which block settings need to be off. Exactly what I needed to know.

Comment: @john-rotenstein what two blocks do you mean to turn off? there is one that controls all and there are other 4 individual options that you can turn on/off.

Comment: @CesarFlores In the individual options, turn off the two that mention **Bucket Policy**.